How to use Broadleaf Commerce CE that is built from source?
after cloning https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce.git into my laptop, I mvn clean install the codebase, and may I ask how to use it to build my own ecommerce web app?
For example,
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
      <artifactId>broadleaf-framework</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
      <artifactId>broadleaf-admin-module</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

I included these 2 dependencies in my pom.xml
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBroadleafAdminAutoConfiguration
public class TestBroadleafApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TestBroadleafApplication.class, args);
    }
}

but with no luck, and got the following error:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field requestProcessor in org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.filter.BroadleafAdminRequestFilter required a bean named 'blMergedDataSources' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("blAdminRequestProcessor")


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'blMergedDataSources' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1

@Configuration
public class BroadleafConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "blMergedDataSources")
    public Map<String, DataSource> dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:file:/data/demo");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        Map<String, DataSource> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
        dataSources.put("blPU", dataSource);

        return dataSources;
    }
}

Tried to add this config class and still error.

i have also done setup today
    <bean id="webDS" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:webdb" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="webSecureDS" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:websecuredb" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="webStorageDS" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:webstoragedb" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="blDS" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:blDB" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

you need to add these 3 dependencies in the path first
Broadleaf\BroadleafCommerce\common\src\test\resources\blc-config\bl-test-applicationContext.xml
also, are you getting the issue
update your configuration like this
public class BroadleafConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }
}

